# Uploading new version of Firefox add-on to AMO keeps prompting for a "Platform"

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, amo

I have an existing Firefox add-on that I originally developed a few years ago using the SDK (*package.json*, etc.). I rewrote the add-on using WebExtensions (*manifest.json*, etc.). When I successfully tested the new version, everything worked fine.

When I went to AMO to upload the new version, 'All Platforms' was checked by default. I could check and uncheck that box or the boxes next to any of the other platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, etc.). I selected my zipped file to upload and eventually was shown a message informing me that the file was uploaded and validated successfully with 0 errors.

However, all of the Platform checkboxes got automatically unchecked after the file upload. Furthermore, they were all disabled. If I click the 'Add Version' button on that form to continue, I just get an error message telling me 'Need at least one platform.' Since I can't check any of the Platform checkboxes because they are now disabled, I can't continue.

As a troubleshooting test, I went ahead and selected my older version's file to upload (the version that was developed using the SDK). With the SDK based file, I didn't experience the unchecking and disabling of the Platform checkboxes. So, I'm not sure what's going on with the WebExtensions version.

Has anyone else experienced this using WebExtensions?

Comment: Please add, at a minimum, your *manifest.json* file.  A, or some, screenshots of the AMO screens would be helpful so we know exactly what is happening. How is your add-on packaged?  What files are contained in your package file?

Comment: Apparently this may be an AMO bug, which I've filed here:  https://github.com/mozilla/addons/issues/173.  It's similar to this bug that was filed previously by another developer having a similar issue:  https://github.com/mozilla/addons/issues/170.  My add-on was packaged as a .zip and also as an .xpi - both produced the same result when uploaded to AMO.

Comment: manifest.json:  https://gist.github.com/lisaclee/50b5a35ef3f26689127a1c16ab32b423

Comment: Interesting it does look like a WebExt bug, thanks for filing it!

Comment: Also interesting:  I removed the 'applications' key from the manifest.json file and was able to successfully upload the package without experiencing the unchecking/disabling of the Platform checkboxes.  Since FF48 was just released today, I guess this is a good workaround, seeing as how FF48 no longer requires the applications key in the manifest.json file anyway.

Comment: Oh wow interesting, thanks for sharing that.